# What is this? Is it LEGO? Dark Green, detailed mouldings, roughly trapezoid shaped

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

I've been sifting through a few gifted bins of LEGO with a small percentage of trash and [clone-brands](/questions/tagged/clone-brands) stuff.  I've had pretty good luck with finding new and strange LEGO pieces on bricklink, but this one has me stumped.

[image: top]

I don't see LEGO printed anywhere on it.  Another discouraging factor is on the bottom where I see numbers that would suggest it is not LEGO:

[image: bottom]

But it fits Technic pins perfectly so maybe it is something LEGO that I've never seen before:

[image: pinned]

So have I been lured in by some clone part or is this a real LEGO thing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's LEGO piece - [47299 - Bionicle Toa Metru Knee Cover](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47299#T=C). You can see © sign in LEGO font as well as "47299" part number on the bottom, both of which confirm this is legit item.